# Is a topological $n-1$ sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ always the boundary of a topological $n$ ball/disk?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In the plane ($n=2$) the assertion is true, it is the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem. The full content of the theorem is false already for $n=3$, due to the Alexander horned sphere. However, the part that it contradicts is that the exterior component is not simply connected, but the interior component still is a topological ball.

The so called "Alexander trick" is tempting, but it assumes the sphere is the boundary of unit ball to begin with... Attempting to adapt the proof in a naive manner fails for non-convex cases.

So - my question is this: Let $M$ be an $n-1$ dimensional sub-manifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$. By the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem, $M$ separates $\mathbb{R}^n$ to two connected components. Is the interior (bounded) component a topological $n$-disc, i.e. homeomorphic to $D^n$, with $M$ as its boundary?

(If it helps - smoothness may be assumed)

Comment: I have no reference, but I believe I have heard that this result is true.

Comment: For $n\ge 3$ you can make a wild sphere wild in both sides. But if you assume the sphere to be tame (e.g. smooth) then the answer is positive in all dimensions.

Comment: Thanks very much. @Moishe Cohen, is this an elementary topological result? I searched quite a bit and it did not come up, although some closely related topics did... could you please provide a lead?

Comment: I can't offer much insight on this, but in case it helps, there seems to be a discrete analog to this question, namely whether or not every simplicial sphere arises as the boundary of a convex polytope. This is false in high dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_sphere  Hopefully that helps or is at least an interesting tangent.

Comment: @DMiz: The existence of sphere wild on both sides is elementary; the tame case is a higher dimensional Schoenflis theorem which is very hard, it is acorollary of the h-cobordism theorem.  The case n=4 is a corollary of Mike Freedman's work. In the smooth category n=4 is a famous open problem; the person who solves it will get a tenure job at a place of his/her choice.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen Many thanks, this has been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For the tame case you want the [generalized Schönflies theorem](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/BrownSchoenflies.pdf) of Brown and Masur.